# Under bound binary search?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

How do I set up my conditions in regular binary search so that I find the largest value x such that f(x) <= t for some critical value t? As opposed to accidentally returning the lowest number > t.

Right now my bounds are

```
if f(x) > t then high = x-1
else if f(x)< t then low = x+1
else return x
```

Main while loop is `while low <= high`

Comment: just return when `f(x) <= t `?

Comment: The largest value where f(x) <=t

Comment: does your set is ordered by f(x)? if not, you cant use binary search...

Comment: @MyNameIsKhan This doesn't really look like binary search. You're supposed to pick the middle value of the bucket that you know your desired answer lies in, not just decrement the size of your search space.

Comment: @Asad No, it is the core of the main while loop of a binary search. x is the middle of the range between low and high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
int ans = -1;

bsearch()
  if f(x) > t then high = x-1
  else if f(x)<= t then low = x+1, ans = x
```

Another method:

Just use your current bsearch to find the x where f(x) is smallest value > t,
then what you want is just x - 1 ? (If exist)

PS: If you are using C++, you can use [upper_bound()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) to find the position of x, then x-1 is your answer